# JSON Angular get value of email and username

Tags: angularjs, json

I am unable to fetch the value of email and username from the following JSON object:

```
{data: {0: 200, username: "user name", email: "email address"}}
```

I need to get the username and email. This is what I have tried:

```
$scope.username = response.data[0]['username'];
$scope.email = response.data[0]['email'];
```

I'm still unable to get the value of username and email.

Comment: It will be hard to help your without the full code. Add the way your handle your API call.
And what's inside `response.data` ?

Comment: If that is object response.data than do $scope.username = response.data.username and $scope.email = response.data.email.

Comment: @sheplu, {0: 200, username: "User name", email: "email address"} is inside response.data

Comment: @lingthe, your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: `response.data.username` and `response.data.email` should work then

Comment: Can you please post whole response.data?

Comment: @lingthe, I have made the edit and posted it in full its: {data: {0: 200, username: "user name", email: "email address"}}

Comment: you should acces like `$scope.userName = response.data.username` if the json you provide ` {data: {0: 200, username: "user name", email: "email address"}}` is right.

Comment: i think joseph Cho has the right answer.

Comment: try please $scope.username  = data.username & $scope.email = data.email

Comment: @lingthe, that hasn't worked but I have found the answer. Will now have to post the answer. I greatly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Your object is flat and not an array, so you don't need to specify an index. If data is really `{0: 200, username: "User name", email: "email address"}` Try running:

```
$scope.username = response.data['username'];
$scope.email = response.data['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this the output of your `request.data`:

```
var data= {0: 200, username: "User name", email: "email address"};
```

The result `data[0]` is **200** and not an **object**.

Therefore to get username and email is just

`data.username` or `data.email`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
$scope.username = response.data.data['username'];
$scope.email = response.data.data['email'];
```